# Field appearing on specific condition

Tags: php, html

I am working on a leave management system for colleges which includes a form for leave application. there are 2 fields which are Number of days of leave & Period of leave. what i need is when the number of days is selected to be more than one, the period of leave should become, from "Date" to "Date". otherwise, when number of days is 1 the period should only be a single date. how can i implement it??
(i've used only html, php and javascript on this project till now)

Comment: You need to add an event listener to the first field and check when its value change. Then make the necessary changes to the DOM tree or whatever. What did you try so far?

Comment: nothing... i am not much experienced in programming... and i dont even know how to implement the thing i mentioned earlier..

Comment: @Praveen You have to try something, at least create an html page with the required fields, javascript for reading the values entered by user. Nobody is going to write the whole code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one approach to is to bind to the blur event of the num days input so that when user exits that field,
you can toggle the visibility of the second date input based on the num days value

```
<label>number of days <label> <input type= text id="num-days">

<p>  <label>start date <label>  <input type="text"  class="datepicker" id="start-date">  </p>

<p id="end-date-wrapper"> <label>end date <label>  <input type="text"  class="datepicker"   id="end-date">  </p>


function toggleEndDate(){
var numDays =  parseInt($("#num-days").val());  //TODO validate integer
$('#end-date-wrapper').toggle(numDays > 1);    
}

toggleEndDate();


$("#num-days").blur(toggleEndDate);



$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

here is a working fiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/FN2mb/1/